# Implementing INotifyCollectionChanged on custom list

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, uwp

I currently have a class in UWP that is a wrapper for a bunch of different types of lists, including a custom-list that I have built. This wrapper needs to bind to some sort of list, either ListView, ListBox, GridView, etc.

The problem is when I am trying to implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`, it seems that the UI element doesn't attatch a handler to the `CollectionChanged` or the `PropertyChanged` handlers (handlers are always `null`). However, changing the list from my custom list to an `ObservableCollection` seems to work fine. What am I missing to get the UI to bind its collection changed to my class?

My current implementation looks like

```
public class MyWrapperList<T> : IList<T>, INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    private IEnumerable<T> _source;

    // Implement all interfaces here, including my custom GetEnumerator() and all my add, insert, remove, etc classes
}
```

Note that I would not like to inheret from `ObservableCollection` like many other answers suggest, due to the fact that I'd like this is a wrapper looking at the original list.

**EDIT:** You can find a sample of the issue reproduceable on GitHub: https://github.com/nolanblew/SampleCollectionChanged/

Comment: It may help you to take a peek at the source for ObservableCollection to see how it does it - https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs - there's not a lot of magic other than having the right event and firing it at the correct time however.

Comment: Thanks. I've taken a look and I can't figure out why my collection changed event isn't being attached to. I'm trying to update the collection through a button, so the UI list is already loaded and all bindings have resolved. But when I get to the code that fires the event, the event handler is always `null`.

Comment: When you set an ItemsSource on a XAML ItemsControl it will automatically try and cast it as an INotifyCollectionChanged and hook up the event, so unless your actual event declaration is faulty there isn't a obvious reason without you posting a small tunable sample project.

Comment: Sure. You can find the sample on GitHub: https://github.com/nolanblew/SampleCollectionChanged/

This should just be a wrapper to the source. I removed my custom code as its in a NDA, but this this should suffice as the problem still presists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have the `ListView` auto-bind to your collection, you must implement *both* `INotifyCollectionChange` **and** `IList` (note: that's the *non-generic* IList).

If you modify your sample code so that your custom list class implements `IList`:

```
public class MyWrapperList<T> : IList<T>, INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyCollectionChanged, IList
{

    //... all your existing code plus: (add your own implementation)

    #region IList 

    void ICollection.CopyTo(Array array, int index) => throw new NotImplementedException();        
    bool IList.IsFixedSize => throw new NotImplementedException();
    bool IList.Contains(object value) => throw new NotImplementedException();       
    int IList.IndexOf(object value) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    void IList.Insert(int index, object value) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    void IList.Remove(object value) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    int IList.Add(object value) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public bool IsSynchronized => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public object SyncRoot { get; } = new object();

    object IList.this[int index] {
        get => this[index];
        set => this[index] = (T) value;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Then the `CollectionChanged` is set when the button click event is fired.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I wish this was more documented though. The only documentation I found on MSDN was suggesting to use an IList, but not saying it was required.